# HIbernate many to one join criteria query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have table1 with key_column as primary key. Table2 has key_column from table1 as foreign key. table2 has many to one relationship to table1.

I want to run a join query.

```
Select table1.*, table2.* from table1, table2 where table2.id = ?
    table2.some_column_other_than_key_column = ? 
    and table1.key_column = table2.key_column

<class name="tbl2class" table="tbl2" lazy="false">
   <many-to-one name="tbl1class" column="key_column"
        class="tbl1Class"
        cascade="none" lazy="false" fetch="join" update="false" insert="true" />

</class>

List<tbl2Class> tbl2List= getSession().createCriteria(tbl2Class.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("tbl1.someColumnOtherThanKeyColumn", messageType))
            .add(Restrictions.or(categoryRestriction, strategyRestriction))
            .list();
```

I get an exception mentiontiong Could not resolve tbl1.someColumnOtherThanKeyColumn - Why - What am I doing incorrectly.

```
public class Tbl1Class 
{
    private Tbl2Class tbl2Class
}
```

Comment: `tbl1.someColumnOtherThanKeyColumn` i think this is incorrect, you have to use `object names` not names in db

Comment: May be I did not make it clear in my example, I am using object names and not table column names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like this

```
Criteria tbl2Criteria = getSession().createCriteria(tbl2Class.class);
tbl2Criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
Criteria tbl1Criteria = tbl2Criteria.createCriteria("tbl1Class");//assuming thats the name of the tbl1 instance in tbl2 class
tbl1Criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("someOtherThanKeyColumn", messageType));
tb12Criteria.add(Restrictions.or(categoryRestriction, strategyRestriction));
List<tbl2Class> result = tbl2Criteria.list();
```